Machine code layout in the memory - Intel x86
I was asked to convert the following machine code to assembly in Intel syntax:
0x421a0770:     0D  00  3D  77
0x421a0774:     AC  3D  11  2A
0x421a0778:     96  AB  77  04
0x421a077c:     90  2D  0D  AB
0x421a0780:     C3  77  2C  C3

I understand that 0d is the opcode of the first instruction and that it is or of eax and an immediate, which means the next 4 bytes represent the immediate. However, I don't understand in what order exactly are those next 4 bytes. I know it uses little endian but I am confused what it means in this situation.
Which one is the correct first instruction?

or eax, 0x003D77AC
or eax, 0xAC773D00
or eax, 0x003D112A
or eax, 0x2A773D00

I used some online converter and it gave me the second option, but as I understand it, in the left column are the MSB so the AC and 77 bytes are not even next to each other in the memory.
I know it is a very basic question, but I couldn't find related information elsewhere.

Where is the 34 in your first 2 options coming from?

"the AC and 77 bytes are not even next to each other in the memory": I disagree. 77 is at 0x421a0773 and AC is at 0x421a0774 (under the reasonable assumption that your memory dump starts with the least significant byte for each line).

I was supposed to be 3D, fixed it.

According to what logic did you arrive at options 3 and 4? It might help you to rewrite that memory dump as just a single line of bytes, so the ordering is more obvious. Seems that's the main source of confusion.

You can probably infer the encoding like this for the basic instructions that work only on registers, but as a whole, instruction encoding on the x86 is quite complex. In part because they've shoehorned more instructions and wider registers in while largely maintaining backwards compatibility.

I think what confuses me is the order of the bytes in each line, is 0D the MSB or LSB of the first line? according to @chtz it is the LSB, but I thought that the opcode suppose to be the MSB

A hexdump (usually) is a sequence of bytes, read left to right, top down, starts at low memory addresses and goes up. (0D @ 0x421a0770, 00 @ 0x421a0771 ...)

x86 has variable-length instructions that aren't aligned to word boundaries, MSB/LSB is not a useful concept here. The decoder looks at things by bytes. The 4-byte immediate is then in little endian (so reversed).

or eax,0xAC773D00 - Little-endian storage applies to instructions too
Intel x86 CPUs store integer values in memory in little-endian order. That means that the least significant byte always occupies the lowest memory address, and each subsequent byte has higher significance.
Integers stored as part of the instruction stream are no different to any other integer stored in memory, so the value is 0xac773d00.
You can verify this yourself by passing your possible candidate instructions through an Online x86 assember:

or eax,0xac773d00 yields 0d 00 3d 77 ac
or eax,0x003d77ac yields 0d ac 77 3d 00

How to read a memory dump
Your option #3 and #4 suggests some confusion about what the memory dump is telling you.
This memory dump has been formatted into rows of four bytes for ease of reading, but from the CPU’s point of view, the memory is organised as a single list - each byte of memory in that list has its own unique address, which is just its position in that really long list.
A memory dump shows the contents of the program memory. The long number in the leftmost column tells you the starting address of each row of the memory dump. Here’s yours:
0x421a0770:     0D  00  3D  77
0x421a0774:     AC  3D  11  2A
0x421a0778:     96  AB  77  04
0x421a077c:     90  2D  0D  AB
0x421a0780:     C3  77  2C  C3

Because the lefthand column is the address of the first byte on each row, the very first byte in this dump, 0d, is at address 0x421a0770. The next byte along, 00 is at address 0x421a0771, the next byte 3d at 0x421a0772 and the last byte on the first row, 77 is at address 0x421a0773. The next byte therefore should be at address 0x421a0774, and that’s exactly what the second line of the memory dump says - the value AC is at 0x421a0774.  The memory is a simple list, one byte after another.
Instruction fetch, decode, fetch some more
When the CPU fetches an instruction, it first grabs the next byte of program memory (strictly, the byte at memory address stored in the Program Counter register, but in normal operation the PC just counts from the start of the program toward the end of the memory). Based on what that byte says, it may then have to fetch more bytes to “complete” the instruction.
In this example, the operation code 0d means “Logical OR the 32 bits of register EAX with an immediate value”. Why is it called an “Immediate” value? because it immediately follows the instruction opcode.  So, in order to perform the operation the CPU will have to fetch a further four bytes from the program stream. These bytes aren’t instructions; they’re the value needed by the OR eax instruction that was just fetched.
So, the next four bytes are 00 3d 77 ac in that order. But Intel x86 CPUs always store integers in memory as the least significant byte first, so the actual value that will be be OR’ed with register eax is ac773d00 hexadecimal (2,893,495,552 decimal).
After the instruction has been fetched, the Program Counter is at address 0x421a0775, ready to read the next opcode, 3d (In this context, “compare EAX with immediate 32-bit value”).
A note about real-world CPU hardware
I should note that what I’ve just described is only a useful mental model of how the CPU works: it is not how a modern CPU actually goes about fetching and decoding instructions. In reality, memory is read in large multi-byte chunks, and multiple instructions can be decoded (and executed) in parallel by the CPU - this is how modern chips can achieve more than one instruction per clock cycle - but all of this complexity is hidden from you, the programmer. Before these modern performance improvements (parallel decoding, micro-operation caches, etc), optimizing code to reduce fetch/decode time was fairly important for getting the very highest loop performance on older CPUs like Pentium III or Core 2, but these days unless you’re doing something that needs the absolute highest performance, you can safely ignore all of that complexity, and and work on assumption that the CPU is reading one byte at a time out of the program memory.
However, if you do want to know more about assembly-language optimization, there’s a wealth of very detailed information at https://agner.org/optimize/ (x86 optimization is item 2).

Real CPUs actually fetch machine code in wider chunks and decode in parallel, but they work as if they looked at one byte at a time.  e.g. they can still decode a two-byte instruction at the end of a page without causing a page-fault on the next page.  But they will fetch from the next page if those first 2 bytes decode as the start of a longer instruction.  (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ajccZ7LdvoQ is Chris Domas's talk from DEFCON, Breaking the x86 Instruction Set, where he uses that technique of bytes at the end of a page and detecting #PF vs. #UD etc. to detect undocumented insns.)

@PeterCordes - that is a fascinating subject, and thanks for the video link, but going into the details of how modern CPU, especially one using the x86 ISA, really handles fetch and decode would have obscured the point that the OP did not understand, which was that from the point of view of the core, and thus the programmer, the instruction memory is linear, and data is fetched from the stream as needed.

Yes, that's just a fun-fact footnote with bonus info, not a criticism of your answer.  If I'd been writing the answer, I might have said "as if" instead of implying that's what physical CPUs actually do.  (Some readers might wonder how something so apparently slow could be how modern x86 actually works...)

@Peter Cordes - a good point, and I’ve added a disclaimer

Don't force yourself into a constraint caused by the shape of the dump, as the dump is a textual representation of a conceptual memory content.
For example, the following dump is 100% equivalent.
0x421a0770:     0D  00  3D  77 AC  3D  11  2A  96  AB  77  04  90  2D  0D  AB 
0x421a0780:     C3  77  2C  C3

As the following is also 100% equivalent:
0x421a0770:     0D 
0x421a0771:     00
0x421a0772:     3D
0x421a0773:     77
0x421a0774:     AC
0x421a0775:     3D
0x421a0776:     11
0x421a0777:     2A
         ...

How do we know this?  It is because the dump is a byte form of dump.  There is no question of endianness for a byte dump.

FYI, A word form (16-bit words) dump would look like this in little endian:
0x421a0770:     000D 773D 3DAC 2A11 AB96 0477 2D90 AB0D 

And like this in big endian:
0x421a0770:     0D00 3D77 AC3D 112A 96AB 7704 902D 0DAB 


It is not possible to do a byte form dump in little or big endian.  So, we must take each byte (numbers of 2 hex digits) as occupying the next sequential storage location.  This is in part because to apply endianness, we would have to be given a size in order to interpret endianness, and we are not given a size (or put other way we are given a size of 1 byte at a time to which no endianness applies).
This is why the word dump presents words (numbers of 4 hex digits), so we know where to apply endianness.  A long word dump would have endianness concerning 4 bytes at a time (so numbers of 8 hex digits), whereas a quad word dump would have endianness concerning 8 bytes at a time (so numbers of 16 hex digits).
Especially for little endian, these larger memory dump sizes are difficult to read, because our data generally involves mixed sizes, including words and strings (bytes), and the dump doesn't know which is where.
Further as x86 instructions are variable length in size, they necessarily cross word, double word and quad word boundaries, so dumping text (machine code) in these larger sizes is also very confusing.

"This is why the word dump presents words (numbers of 4 hex bytes)" Didn't you mean to say "4 hex digits" ?

@SepRoland, yes, thanks!
